# print gremlin query being run without repeating code

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I would like to **print the query** being run for debugging.
I can't figure out the best way to do so without repeating the query twice, once as string to be printed, once to actually execute it.

i tried:
`add_vertex_query = "g.addV('addvqueryLabel').next()"`
`print("going to run query: %s"%(add_vertex_query))`
`add_vertex_query_res = add_vertex_query`
`print("add_vertex_query result: %s"%(add_vertex_query_res))`
but this doesn't work because it is just reassigning the query string and not actually running it, in the 3rd line

btw I am running my graph in **Neptune** so it'd be nice if the solution is Neptune-compatible

**UPDATE**
I have found an **alternative** (though *not ideal*):

```
query = g.V().valueMap(True)
print("query: %s"%(query))
result_list = query.toList()
print("result: %s"%(result_list))
```

this gives
`query: [['V'], ['valueMap', True]]`
in the printout, which can be understood to be
"`g.V().valueMap(True)`"
but ideally best case would be if I can log/print the exact entire query I intended:
`g.V().valueMap(True).toList()`
without having to duplicate the string in the code like

```
query_string = "g.V().valueMap(True).toList()"
print("running query: %s"%(query_string))
res = g.V().valueMap(True).toList()
print("results: %s"%(res))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Python `eval`

```
query_string = "g.V().valueMap(True).limit(5).toList()"
print("running query: %s ..."%(query_string))
res_list = eval(query_string)
[print("result %s: %s"%(i, res)) for i, res in enumerate(res_list, 1)]
```